# Starting issue using expo of a react native sample from turbo

Tags: expo, react-navigation, monorepo, turbo, expo-go

I have a monorepo react native application sample "turbo-repo" that i created using  :
npx create-turbo -e with-react-native-web

I run the build using the command :
npx turbo build

Then i started the application using :
npx expo start

When i scanned the generated QR code using Expo Go on android to open the native application,
the application starts showing an empty screen , rather than a button as implemented in the turbo-repo sample.

how can i inspect the problem ? how to fix it ?

I expect to have a screen with a button as implemented in the turbo-repo sample.